# error after django-announcements installation

Tags: django

I have recently installed `django-announcements` in my project by following the installation guide here - [django-announcements](http://django-announcements.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html)

but after installation, when I run the application (`runserver`), I get the error on console

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

To debug this I undo the changes for the `django-announcements` installation and then the application works fine.

Searching around I also find that it might to recent django 1.7 migration that I had done and need to change the `wsgi.py` to include

```
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

But this is already done in my project. Please let me know if I am missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of django announcements that you have installed is not compatible with Django 1.7.

It looks as if it might have been fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/pinax/django-announcements/commit/bda39727f2c9158c0bb5eba1604b44f14deae5b0), but there hasn't been a release since then.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out..Can you please suggest any other announcement like app compatible with django 1.7?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any suggestions for alternative apps.